# Cannot call json.load() on tempfile

Tags: python

Why is it that I can't read from this temp file after writing? Note that the `.read()` from `json.load()` is erroring.

```
In [30]: import tempfile

In [31]: fp = tempfile.TemporaryFile("w")

In [32]: import json

In [33]: json.dump("hi", fp)

In [34]: fp.seek(0)
Out[34]: 0

In [35]: json.load(fp)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ba076023b2da> in <module>
----> 1 json.load(fp)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    291     kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
    292     """
--> 293     return loads(fp.read(),
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: It looks like you are opening file in write mode. Please open it in read mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Divakar Patil. I had to open the file in both read **and** write mode:

`tempfile.TemporaryFile("r+")`